# Why does this function not change the cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, session-cookies

I am coding, but this does not seem to change this cookie. Please give me advice.

```
function ChangeCookie(loginuser){
document.cookie = "user="+loginuser;
}
```

When I call this function, this cookie does not seem to change, instead, it would do nothing. I tried to go from this to

```
document.cookie = "user=loginuser"
```

But this would not work either.

EDIT: I have tried this in the console and it works, but this is not working for this HTML. Please tell me what is wrong with this HTML

```
<?php
$cookie_name="user";
$cookie_value="anony"
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 7), "/");
?>
<script>
function ChangeCookie(loginuser){
document.cookie = "user="+loginuser;
}
</script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please enter your username</p>
<form name="myForm" action="/index.html" onsubmit="return ChangeCookie(document.GetElementById("user"))" method="post">
<input type="text" id="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Are you calling the function?

Comment: Why are you guys downvoting this question without a reason?

Comment: @Mehdi I am calling this function, but the cookie isn't showing up in editthiscookie.

Comment: Probably because you didn't post any explanation nor errors, the question doesn't show debugging efforts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Mehdi

Comment: You are welcome, try and debug the code. How was the cookie created? is it accessible from JavaScript? how are you calling the function? check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try a little debugging to see what you're passing into the function. One way to do this is to write something to the console:

```
function ChangeCookie(loginuser) {
  // log the parameter value
  console.log(loginuser);
  document.cookie = "user="+loginuser;
}
// call the function immediately
ChangeCookie(loginuser);

//verify whether or not the value was set
console.log(document.cookie);
```

Another way is to use `debugger`:

```
function ChangeCookie(loginuser) {
  debugger;
  document.cookie = "user="+loginuser;
}
ChangeCookie(loginuser);
```

If you run the above with you console open it should allow you to see the value of the variable you're passing in. You will also have access to the variable via the console.

Comment: This seems to work in console but does not work in html. Why?